# Compare two models of binomial distributions via Bayes Factor

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, bayesian, statistical-significance, bayes-factors

(This question is similar to [How to compare two models of binomial distributions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281644/how-to-compare-two-models-of-binomial-distributions?rq=1), except that I would like to use a Bayes Factor for model selection)

I have a bunch of binary (Bernoulli distributed) data, and split it into two groups (with failures $n_1, n_2$ and successes $k_1, k_2$, assumed independent).

Now, I want to test whether splitting the data provides a significant improvement over leaving it all in one bucket.

For that, I consider the following hypothesis:

- $H_1$: The two groups are drawn from $Binom(p_1)$ and $Binom(p_2)$, respectively, with

  $$p_1 \sim Beta(\underbrace{k_1 + k_p}_{\alpha_1}, \underbrace{n_1 + n_p}_{\beta_1})$$ and $$p_2 \sim Beta(\underbrace{k_2 + k_p}_{\alpha_2}, \underbrace{n_2 + n_p}_{\beta_2})$$

($k_p$, $n_p$ are parameters representing my prior on $p$)

And this null Hypothesis:

- $H_0$: All data is drawn from $Binom(p_{tot})$ with $$p_{tot} \sim Beta(\underbrace{k_1 + k_2 + k_p}_{\alpha_{tot}}, \underbrace{n_1 + n_2 + n_p}_{\beta_{tot}})$$

I want to compare these hypotheses by calculating their Bayes Factor, but I'm unsure how to do it, since it involves comparing two probability distributions to one.

#### My attempt

The joint PDFs of the two observations are:

- $H_1$: $$P(k_1, k_2, n_1, n_2 \mid p_1, p_2) = P(k_1, n_1 \mid p_1) \cdot P(k_2, n_2 \mid p_2)$$
- $H_0$: \begin{align} P(k_1, k_2, n_1, n_2 \mid p_{tot}) &= P(k_1, n_1 \mid  p_{tot}) \cdot P(k_2, n_2 \mid p_{tot})\\ &= \frac{\binom{n_1 + k_1}{k_1}\binom{n_2 + k_2}{k_2}}{\binom{n_1 + k_1 + n_2 + k_2}{k_1 + k_2}} P(k_1 + k_2, n_1 + n_2 \mid p_{tot})\end{align}

Giving a Bayes Factor $K$:

$$ K = \frac{P(D \mid H_1)}{P(D \mid H_0)} $$

$$ = \frac{\iint P(k_1, k_2, n_1, n_2 \mid p_1, p_2) P(p_1) P(p_2) dp_1 dp_2}{\int P(k_1, k_2, n_1, n_2 \mid p_{tot})  P(p_{tot}) dp_{tot}}$$

$$ = \frac{\int P(k_1, n_1 \mid p_1) P(p_1) dp_1 \cdot \int P(k_2, n_2 \mid p_2) P(p_2) dp_2}{\frac{\binom{n_1 + k_1}{k_1}\binom{n_2 + k_2}{k_2}}{\binom{n_1 + k_1 + n_2 + k_2}{k_1 + k_2}}\int P(k_1 + k_2, n_1 + n_2 \mid p_{tot}) P(p_{tot}) dp_{tot}}$$

which can be solved analytically, since there are only Beta and Binomial distributions involved.

#### Now, I have two questions:

1. Is this approach a valid solution to the posed problem?
2. $H_1$ is obviously more complex than $H_0$, since it involves two parameters instead of one. Does computing the Bayes Factor this way already account for that? If not, what kind of additional model prior do people typically impose to capture this kind of complexity?

Comment: A Bayes factor is not "just the ratio of total data likelihood".  There is integration over the prior distributions *within* each model and that can address your question of complexity. Consider the [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor#Example)

Comment: I adopted the language from [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/97853/124621). The expression I give for K is after the integration (I guess with a uniform model prior).

Comment: Please try to read the relevant section of a proper textbook, rather than cut&paste-ing from another X validated answer.

Comment: See eg [The philosophy of Bayes factors and the quantification of statistical evidence](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022249615000723?via%3Dihub)

Comment: I updated the question to make it clearer that I am integrating over the posterior. If you still think it is flawed, I'd be grateful if you could point out the specific problem with it.